# Why do some words have a Double L

Tags: difference

Examples are Full & Fill .And some do not.

As in Fail,Beautiful Nail.

It seems the use of the letter L is subjective.

Comment: You might start by checking the word origins, since English words are derived from many languages.

Answer (score 1):

Because English spelling isn't phonetic.

In a number of cases where a double 'll' occurs at the end of a word, it is due to a lost final syllable. For example Old English "Fyllan" became modern English fill, retaining the double "ll" but losing the final sound. Similarly "Bell" and "grill" were "belle" and "graille".

On the other hand nail was "nægl" with a single l.

*There is no logic or rule that can explain this*. Spelling in the 16th century was very flexible. Different writers used different spellings (sometimes even in the same work) The influence of London printers began to regularise spellings, and the dictionary writers did more to fix the idea that there is a single correct way of spelling each word.

There is no logic that can explain why "Aprille" didn't keep a double 'll' Or explain why "hell" (which was "hel" in Old English) is spelled with the double ll.